# how to specify use of STC algorithm in Solr admin console?

Tags: algorithm, solr, cluster-analysis, carrot2

I have a test Solr environment using Carrot2 on Ubuntu. With the Carrot2 workbench I can alternate between the three defined algorithms (Lingo, STC, kmeans). How do I do the same thing in the Solr admin query tool? is it an argument passed with the clustering parameter?

All 3 algorithms are defined in the solrconfig.xml, which is by and large a copy of the example from collection1. I'm inferring it is using Lingo by default but not sure where to switch it to STC if I'd like.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`clustering.engine`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ClusteringComponent#clustering.engine) parameter to select the clustering engine at query time. To cluster the results with STC, add `clustering.engine=stc` to your request. In Solr Admin, you can pass the extra parameter in the Raw Query Parameters field of the query screen. You may also need to change the default Request-Handler to the one that has results clustering enabled.